# How can I thank a user for editing (and improve) my answer?

Tags: support, feature-request, editing, community

Most of my answers are full of spelling and grammar errors (nothing a spell checker can help). But fortunately there are some users who (often) edit my answers and fix all (or most) of those mistakes. But unfortunately I've found no method to thank those people. AFAIK there's no up vote for revisions or a kind of comment a revision only without commenting the public answer.

It would be nice to simply be able to say "thank you".

Answer (score 9):

A feature for personal messaging between users has been declined earlier. One reason is, that communication should be publicly visible, and the community should be able to moderate, which is also spam protection.

So you could post a public comment thanking the user. You can delete it later, keeping the site tidy.

Indeed, not everything can be upvoted, so there's work which isn't be rewarded by reputation. We know that score doesn't tell everything. In some cases, rare badges show who did much work such as edits.

If I noticed, that a user makes good contributions such as editing posts and wikis, I have a look at his user profile page and browse through his answers and questions. When I see good contributions there, I can vote up and I do it. So there's a way you can thank a helpful user: read his or her contributions and vote to it, which you otherwise would perhaps have overlooked if the user didn't draw your attention because of his improvements.

Furthermore, you could directly return the favour: if you notice a good answer by that user which could be improved, just do it, directly or via edit suggestion feature. So his or her answer gets better and could earn upvotes. Same for questions: a bit unclear question could be made a great question or even a canonical one.

Links for the background:

- [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)
- [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)
- [Private Messages - Will StackChat reopen the debate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57203/private-messages-will-stackchat-reopen-the-debate)

Comment: Another alternative which is public, but less so in practice, is to thank them in chat using  @<name>.  This doesn't clutter up the question, but the person will get notified.  Other chatters will see it but in practice it will be not seen by most other users.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Good suggestion - maybe even a solution.

Comment: Going through their answers and voting for them is slightly dangerous as it might trigger the "sock puppet" script!  I think that Alan's comment is good, and the paragraph "Furthermore" is also good but I'd make it more general: the favour doesn't have to be returned to the user who made the edit on your question.

Comment: @AndrewStacey True, I also meant with tact, not SP like. Regarding giving back also to others: the OP wanted to thank a specific user. I agree with you: the favour can be returned also to other users, so we all benefit and this is for sure in the meaning of the original user.